# Restarting a Java program automatically

Tags: java, batch-file, jenkins

I run the jenkins slave node on my PC from an executed batch file, command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" -jar "C:\JenkinsSlave\agent.jar" -jnlpUrl https://jenkins-xxx.xxx.intra.xxx.com:8080/computer/xxxxx/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 8b81565f01297a39
```

Sometimes I see that the program fails, and stops the batch file execution, and somebody would need to log in to the PC, and re execute the batch file again.

Is there any way I can programmatically in my batch file, check if the above java application crashed, or stopped for some reason, and then restart it.

Comment: Your question has nothing whatsoever to do with your code, and as such it is not a code question requiring our assistance. What you're seeking is an answer to the research question in the last sentence of your question body.

Comment: Mimic a watchdog: Check if the program still works. If not: kill and restart

Comment: The jenkinsslave is a 3rd party software for which i dont have control of it.

Answer (score 1):

The windows operating system has means to ensuire a process is running. You just need to register it correctly as a service.

To do that for java applications, check out one these service wrappers (there are definitely more available):

- https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp
- http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/

Comment: How does the wrapper know if the application stalled and needs to be restarted ?

Comment: Check the documentation: https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/qna-monitor.html. The other one has similar features for sure.

Comment: This looks promising .. will try it out. Thanks